# Entering cyrillic characters using compose key

Tags: xorg, keyboard, compose-key

I'd like to know how to add cyrillic characters to the compose-key without removing any of the existing characters that I have.

Comment: That's not a question. It's a statement. What have you tried and where did you encounter trouble? You can create a custom .XCompose file with any sequences you like. Google that, give it a try, and if you can't get it to work, then ask here.

Comment: I already know about the .XCompose file. If the only answer I get i "do a Google search" the there is absolutely no point being here, I may as well just do a "Google search'' for everything that I ask here ergo a waste of time being here..

Comment: If you're going to have that attitude, then, yes, you're wasting your time being here. This is a Q&A site, not a "I want other people to write a tutorial for me" site.